# Optimise SQL Alchemy request with relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask and SQL Alchemy for a Web-App.

I have a many-to-many relationship like this one :

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'link'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))
    url = Column(String(128))

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))
    links = relationship("Link",
                         secondary=Table('association', Base.metadata,
                                         Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('category.id')),
                                         Column('link_id', Integer, ForeignKey('link.id'))),
                         backref="categories")
```

So I got `links` and `categories`.

When requesting links in order to show them, and their categories, I'm doing this :

```
links = Link.query.all()
for link in links:
    print link.name
    for categorie in link.categories
        print categorie.name
```

It's working fine, but the problem is, for each `link.categories` call, a SQL query is performed. So if I got 10 links, 11 queries will be done (1 for getting links and one per link for gettings categories).

Isn't it possible to perform it in one query with Flask ? (using `JOIN`)
(I don't want to write SQL query, I want to use ORM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer my self.
When querying the models, I just need to add the option `joinedload('categories')` like this :

```
links = Link.query.options(joinedload('categories')).all()
for link in links:
    print link.name
    for categorie in link.categories
        print categorie.name
```

Now, only one SQL query is performed.

Comment: You can also configure that option in the relationship using `lazy='joined'` or `lazy='subquery'`